# Save editable text on input and save into db

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an input for a bitcoin wallet address, but I need 13 more, and this code is very long and would be huge, besides I've tried this way and it didn't work. How you would do this simply?

This alone works very well, the user has the wallet you want and clicks update and is saved in the database.

[image: Wallet]

**My html:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        {{ method_field('POST') }}

                                        <span><i>Wallet:</i></span>
                                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted text-center">
                                         <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitcoin wallet code" name="bitzpayer_id2" value="{{old('bitzpayer_id2') ? old('bitzpayer_id2') : Auth::user()->bitzpayer_id2}}"/>
                                               <span class="input-group-btn">
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Update</button>
                                          </span>
                                      </div>
                                  </small>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: Hi question is not clear enough, please review.

Comment: Be specific about your problem.

Comment: my english is terrible, what I want is to save in the database everything that is typed in the input as it is in the photo

Answer (score 0):

You can make 13 different form with a hidden text field called id.

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{ $id }}" />
```

Then you will have your desired request data.

Comment: The point is that only 1 works, but if I take every script, copy and paste with different ID, it doesn't work, because only 1 script is huge.

Comment: You have to give each form with it's own submit button. So you need 13 submit button too